# Mothballing Integra for nine months

Tags: starting, acura, long-term-storage

I plan to garage a 95 Integra for 9-ish months in Florida garage.  I plan to use a fuel stabilizer and disconnect the battery.   The battery will be put on a trickle charger 3 days before starting.  What additional steps can be taken:

- before day 0 (preparation)?
- when starting up for the first time after months?

The goal is to prep the vehicle for a flawless first start.

Comment: There are other questions about this topic on here - worth you looking at them...

Comment: See this as similar: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/2281/10976

Comment: Instead of putting the battery on a trickle charger three days before startup, I'd suggest leaving the battery on a battery *maintainer* the entire time it is in storage, if at all possible. Trickle chargers feed a continuous 1-2Amps of juice the entire time, while a battery maintainer monitors the battery and keeps it topped off and in good shape the entire time. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

As @SolarMike says, there's quite a few questions on similar subjects here - see the long-term-storage tag and the linked question

There's only one thing I'd add to the answers in the linked question, and that is to consider the environment you're storing it in - Florida is known for a warm, damp climate, which is ideal conditions for mould and mildew to form, so make sure the inside of the car stays dry - you may want to consider using a passive dehumidifer or similar.

Comment: Or using a climate controlled storage space.

Comment: I suppose keeping the windows open or cracked is also good (assuming it is in a garage).

Answer (score 1):

If you have not changed your oil in "a while", I would recommend changing the oil. This does 2 things:

1. It means that when you start using the car again next Nov/Dec, you know exactly how long you have before your next oil change.
2. Even more importantly, small amounts of water can build up in the oil. Normally, this water evaporates and is sucked out of the crankcase. However, there are a number of reasons why this might not happen. It is better to be safe and get it all out before it sits for an extended period of time.

(Also: top off your gas tank before you put the car away.)